# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from UDF_DTTM_3#54: need struct type but got timestamp;

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Code :

```
JavaRDD<RuleParamsBean> javaRDD = ds.toJavaRDD();
```

org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.toJavaRDD() function throws this error .

I have many fields in `RuleParamsBean,java` class.

One of them is : `UDF_DTTM_3` for which error is being thrown.

below is the declaration and setter getter methods.

```
private Date UDF_DTTM_3;
public Date getUDF_DTTM_3() {
        return UDF_DTTM_3;
    }
    public void setUDF_DTTM_3(Date uDF_DTTM_3) {
        UDF_DTTM_3 = uDF_DTTM_3;
    }
```

I am not able to understand why this error is being thrown.

If more details are required , do let me know.

**EDIT**

**UDF_DTTM_3** has datatype **DATE** in oracle DB.

**UDF_DTTM_3** has datatype **java.util.Date** in RuleParamsBean.java

Comment: @SHG ok removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I changed **UDF_DTTM_3** datatype from **java.util.Date** to **java.sql.Date** in `RuleParamsBean.java` class above error is resolved.

Comment: I had the same error using spark SQL. Unfortunately, this is a java solution. Any suggestion?